# Cannot execute GraphQL query from Angular

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, graphql, apollo

I'm serving `/graphql` endpoint from my SpringBoot backend, my schema looks more or less like this

```
type Query {
    findUsers(searchQuery: String!): [UserData]
}

type UserProfile {
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
}

type UserData {
    profile: UserProfile!
    mutualFriends: Int!
}
```

And executing this query from Intelij GraphqlJS plugin works fine

```
{
    findUsers(searchQuery:  "john doe") {
        profile {
            firstName
            lastName
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm having troubles executing same query from Angular

I have query

```
const findUsersQuery =
  gql`
    query findUsers($searchQuery: String!) {
      profile {
        firstName
        lastName
      }
    }
`;
```

And I execute it this way

```
this.apollo.watchQuery({
  query: findUsersQuery,
  variables: {
    searchQuery: 'john doe'
  }
}).valueChanges.subscribe(({data}) => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

But on server side, I see this error in logs (to be precise, the same error returns with HTTP response to the browser)

```
2020-11-25 20:25:22.798  WARN 2956 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] graphql.GraphQL                          : Query failed to validate : 'query findUsers($searchQuery: String!) {
  profile {
    firstName
    lastName
    __typename
  }
}
'
```

Comment: read about declaring variables and passing arguments in graphql

Answer (score 0):

After changing query in Angular to this, it's working.

```
const findUsersQuery =
  gql`
    query findUsers($searchQuery: String!) {
      findUsers(searchQuery: $searchQuery) {
        profile {
          firstName
          lastName
        }
    }
  }
`;
```